# Grok custom pattern for space delimited file

Tags: amazon-athena, grok

I'm trying to load a file to structured table in Athena. I am using GROK pattern to load it to the table but not able to find the correct pattern. The file format is as below:

```
L1127          ACTUALS   214171              ON      27649075                                            -00000000000000000409618.02                          601 MBS  DAILY VISION - CAN OS         

L1127          ACTUALS   412821              ON      27649075  002060                                    -00000000000000000002657.33                          521 MBS  DAILY VISION - CAN OS
```

GROK pattern I'm using:

```
(?<BusinessUnit>.{5})%{SPACE}(?<Type>.{7})%{SPACE}(?<PSGLAccountNumber>.{6})%{SPACE}(?<Province>.{2})%{SPACE}(?<DepartmentId>.{8})%{SPACE}(?<ProductId>.{6})%{SPACE}(?<Amount>.{27})%{SPACE}(?<TransCode>.{3})%{SPACE}(?<Feed>.{35})
```

I'm having trouble when the ProductId has no value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`(?<ProductId>.{6})%{SPACE}` means that you expect the `ProductId` field to be exactly six characters followed by any number of spaces. From the data you posted it seems to me that what should happen is that in the first row `ProductId` would end up as six spaces.

If the problem is that it becomes six spaces and you want it to be an empty string, you could for example use `(?<ProductId>\S*)%{SPACE}` (`\S*` matches zero or more non-space characters).

If this does not solve your problem, perhaps you could describe in some more detail what trouble you are having, and what you want to happen?

---

*Update:* in a comment you indicated that the problem with this solution is that the `ProductId` column becomes "-00000". The reason for that is that the `%{SPACE}` pattern *before* `(?ProductId…` consumes all the spaces between the `DepartmentId` and `Account` fields. To solve this you could for example limit the number of spaces that can appear between the `DepartmentId` and `ProductId` fields. In the example data you post there are two spaces, and since the fields are fixed-width I assume this is always the case. Using a pattern like `…(?<DepartmentId>.{8})\s{2}(?<ProductId>\S*)%{SPACE}(?<Amount>.{27})…` should fix the problem.

Comment: I need the ProductId as empty string if it has just SPACES and if it has a value I need the value.

By using the GROK pattern above if the ProductId is empty then it prints as -00000 which is not correct.

Comment: I've updated the answer, see if the suggestion works.

Comment: If the ProductId is empty then it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work using the below pattern below

```
%{WORD:BusinessUnit}%{SPACE}%{WORD:Type}%{SPACE}%{POSINT:PSGLAccountNumber}%{SPACE}%{WORD:Province}%{SPACE}%{POSINT:DepartmentId}%{SPACE}%{custompat:ProductId}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:Amount}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:TransCode}%{SPACE}(?<Feed>[A-Za-z0-9\-\s]{26})
```

And using custom pattern:

```
custompat ([0-9]{6}|\s{6})
```